# how to install VMware image on a hard drive partition

Tags: virtualization, vmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate from a virtual box vm to a physical system.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-box-vm-to-a-physical-system)

how to install VMware image on a hard drive partition?

Comment: Please add some more information to your question, do you want to transfer the OS from a VM image to a physical partition ? Does the image contains an Ubuntu VM ?

Comment: Yes, I want to transfer OS from image to a physical patrition. Image didn't contain ubuntu, it contains Mac (

Comment: i seriously doubt that will work , and since this is not ubuntu related i thinks this is off topic here

Comment: I don't think its off-topic, but it would probably be better on unix.stackexchange or superuser.stackexchange or something.