# how to move a raw disk image to a pendrive to make it bootable?

Tags: virtualbox

I tried to follow this: [Migrate from a virtual machine (VM) to a physical system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system/32506#32506) but it is not working for me.

I have a working xubuntu vdi image. I converted it like this:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw mydisk.vdi /home/wojtek/Pobieranie/disk.img
```

Then I tried to move it to a newly formated pendrive:

```
sudo dd if=/home/wojtek/Pobieranie/mydisk.img of=/dev/sdb1
```

I got this:

```
18874368+0 records in
18874368+0 records out
9663676416 bytes (9.7 GB) copied, 2831.46 s, 3.4 MB/s
```

But now I can't even mount my pendrive. It's shown as unformatted with all the space left. It doesn't boot as expected.

What did I do wrong?

I should have used sudo dd if=/home/wojtek/Pobieranie/mydisk.img of=/dev/sdb, not sudo dd if=/home/wojtek/Pobieranie/mydisk.img of=/dev/sdb1 as Mike pointed out. Thanks Mike!

Comment: I suspect, the `dd` command should have looked like this: `sudo dd if=/home/wojtek/Pobieranie/mydisk.img of=/dev/sdb`. Note that `/dev/sdb` is not the same as `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: Please @mikewhatever add your comment as an answer, so rrh can accept it. Good catch, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The `dd` command should look like this:

```
sudo dd if=/home/wojtek/Pobieranie/mydisk.img of=/dev/sdb
```

...in other words, `/dev/sda1` is not the same as `/dev/sda`.