# Create edited boot ISO file of Ubuntu, i386-pc not found

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox

I have a dual boot system with Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus) on different partitions. I am trying to configure a Virtual Machine in Windows, which can access the already installed Ubuntu.

I am following the instructions at: [Using a Physical Hard Drive Pariition as a VirtualBox VM and as a Bootable Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571965/using-a-physical-hard-drive-pariition-as-a-virtualbox-vm-and-as-a-bootable-parti)

I got to step where I have to copy `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/*` to  `~/Desktop/iso/boot/grub`. However, these is no `i386-pc` directory(I think because I have AMD processor), the directories I see in

```
/usr/lib/grub/:
grub-mkconfig_lib  x86_64-efi  x86_64-efi-signed
```

As I don't have i386-pc, which files do I need to copy over to create the GRUB Recovery ISO, which the Virtual Machine will use to boot into Ubuntu?

I tried to use `x86_64-efi/*` to create ISO file and load it to VM, but the VM says:
FATAL: Could not read from from the boot medium! System halted.
Is there any way to create grub boot iso file with edited `grub.cfg` on my machine?(As in the link was mentioned, it is important to delete windows configuration so that I would not be able to start the OS twice, that would break the whole system)

Laptop Acer E5-553, processor: AMD 9600P, virtualization: on,

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found out that I needed to turn on EFI in the Virtual Box. So the solution will be:

> Use x86_64-efi instead of i386-pc, copy all the internal files to
>   grub folder and continue the guide.