# How do I enlarge an encrypted LVM partition in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: encryption, lvm, 20.04

I would like to enlarge my encrypted LVM partition, because I gave my virtual machine Ubuntu 20.04 more hard disk space.

I tried to use Gparted, but it gave an error. I also tried the answer on [How to expand an encrypted ubuntu partition with LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747073/how-to-expand-an-encrypted-ubuntu-partition-with-lvm), but `sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root` doesn't work, because `/dev/ubuntu-vg/root` doesn't exist.

How can I easily enlarge an encrypted partition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

#### Live CD

Launch the live CD and use the option "Try Ubuntu".

#### Instal Partitionmanager

Make sure the universe software can be downloaded:

- go to the Activities
- launch Software & Updates
- enable `universe`

Open the terminal and install the Partitionmanager:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install partitionmanager
```

#### Partitionmanager

See also the instructions here: http://e1z.ca/devlog/encrypted_partition_resize.html

Open the partitionmanger with sudo rights:

```
sudo partitionmanager
```

Right click on the encrypted volume and `unlock`.

Resize the partition. You might need to resize the `vgubuntu` on the left as well.

Comment: GParted now seems to offer similar functionality, without having to install a chunk of the KDE system in order to run Partitionmanager.

Comment: Even after resizing vgubuntu, my /home partition was failing to recognize additional space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

I tab completed it and it worked fine, you just had the path wrong.