# Ubuntu didn't used the whole disk while installation

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

I'm using *Ubuntu 20.04 LTS "Focal"* with **ppc64le** architecture (mage was: `http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server-ppc64el.iso`) in a qemu virtual machine with an Debian 11 (AMD64) as host. The VM has a 25GB emulated hard disk. But the guest only shows me round about 12GB.

Why?

I didn't increased the size of the virtual hard disk. It was 25GB from the beginning when I installed Ubuntu on it. I don't understand why Ubuntu didn't used the whole disk. I didn't modified the default values of the installer.

```
user@brinkmann:~/work$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              405M   15M  391M   4% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   12G   12G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          63M   63M     0 100% /snap/core20/1612
/dev/loop1                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1625
/dev/loop2                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22757
/dev/loop3                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16780
/dev/loop4                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17030
/dev/vda2                          2,0G  123M  1,7G   7% /boot
tmpfs                              405M     0  405M   0% /run/user/1000

user@brinkmann:~/work$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

I need to increase the swapfile on hard disk.

```
user@brinkmann:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 62,2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1612
loop1                       7:1    0 63,5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1625
loop2                       7:2    0 61,1M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22757
loop3                       7:3    0 43,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16780
loop4                       7:4    0 43,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17030
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda                       252:0    0   25G  0 disk 
├─vda1                    252:1    0    8M  0 part 
├─vda2                    252:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
└─vda3                    252:3    0   23G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 11,5G  0 lvm  /
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enlarge an encrypted LVM partition in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227998/how-do-i-enlarge-an-encrypted-lvm-partition-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: No, sorry. Because I haven't increased my disk. The problem here is that Ubuntu didn't used the whole 25GB while installing and I don't understand why.

Comment: "I need to increase the swapfile on hard disk." Does this answer your question? [Increase swap in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264568/increase-swap-in-20-04)

Comment: No it did not. I know how to increase swap. But I can't because there is no much space on the disk available because Ubuntu us only 12 GB of 25.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lsblk` in your Ubuntu VM.

Comment: `sudo lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ` did not work. "No free space left" I didn't tried the `partitionmanager` because no X installed and no live CD available.