# how to create a iso installation of current ubuntu server?

Tags: server, system-installation, iso

I have a ubuntu server 15.10 installed on my virtual machine (Parallels Desktop). now I want to create a iso installation of my current ubuntu server with it's softwares, configuration, etc.

as long as its a non-gui distribution, how would I manage to do that? I have tested some tools like Remastersys, Respin, PinguyBuilder but despite the Live mode which works correctly and have my data included, their Installer option doesn't work, and when I choose it, the system is going to freeze or into Live mode again.

I don't want to use CloneZilla because as far as I know it is just a backup/restore tool and doesn't come for creating iso installation.

Comment: Are you intending migrating this VM to a physical installation?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: This answer should help http://askubuntu.com/a/32506/320386

Comment: @Arronical Firstly that was for ubuntu desktop, right?
secondly I'm using Parallels Desktop on Mac, not VMWare or VirtualBox.

Comment: Server or desktop will make absolutely no difference. I think you may have trouble creating an iso, the better way would be to make an image of the disk somehow, and restore this to your physical disk. `dd` is good for this, `dd_rescue` may be better as it has extra functions, that I think make it easier to use. `dd` is only dangerous if you get the command wrong, such as writing to the partition that you're meant to read from. You just need to make sure you understand what it is you want to do, before trying anything, and you could obviously back up your VM first.

Comment: in case of making installer interface, it make difference. Also backup and restore already could be accomplished through CloneZilla. I want a directly iso installation.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just duplicate the VM?

I usually separate the `/home`, `/var` and data partitions. you could do a vanilla installation and copy the /etc hierarchy over.

Another way to go is to use dd_rescue to create an image you can later dump to another machine VM.

Comment: I want to move this installation into a physical computer. how can I duplicate that?!
I searched about dd and people said it's dangerous, so I'm looking for another easy stuff.

Comment: Restoring a complete system from a back up - any back up - is dangerous. dd_rescue (not the standard, older, dd) is safer and more powerful. If you follow the instructions and take precautions - it'll be OK.