# Create Ubuntu Installation from Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualbox

17.04 has just been released and for a few reasons I don't want to upgrade, but rather I'd prefer roll back to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have a VirtualBox VM running 16.04 which is partially setup in that it has Chrome installed and some other programs. While doing this I had the idea of setting up a virtual machine running Ubuntu, installing and setting up all my programs and then being able to replace my current Ubuntu installation with this. That way, I can make sure everything works and I can get started immediately without having to re-add PPAs and install applications again.

Is it possible to do this? I tried looking it up online and I found no information on this whatsoever. It would be nice to just pick up and start using my computer again after installation rather than running into situations where I'm missing a program such as Kdenlive or Steam.

Comment: You can clone your virtual machine with Clonezilla then load it on to a real machine.  See this: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1946-copying-a-virtual-linux-system-from-virtualbox-to-a-real-physical-machine Other methods are here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system

Comment: I'd like to add to @DavidFoerster comment, that although it is possible to do this, it may be better to simply perform a clean install of Ubuntu rather than work with what could be a potentially messy process.