# server is running out of space for php-apps (show error for creating temps etc.)

Tags: lvm

Seems my (Ubuntu 16.04) running on (Ubuntu 16.04) Linux host as a virtual maschine with dynamic file size for vdi runs out of space, maybe see:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/dirk# df -h
Dateisystem                 Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev                         2,9G       0  2,9G    0% /dev
tmpfs                        597M     31M  567M    6% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  5,4G    5,1G     0  100% /
tmpfs                        3,0G    4,0K  3,0G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5,0M       0  5,0M    0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        3,0G       0  3,0G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M     58M  390M   13% /boot
tmpfs                        597M       0  597M    0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs                        597M       0  597M    0% /run/user/1000
/home/dirk/.Private          5,4G    5,1G     0  100% /home/dirk
```

On the host is enough free space that vdi can expand, maybe see:

```
dirk@ubuntu:/media/dirk/59b80d1c-3259-4cf7-b56e-0b24d55f1111$ df -h
Dateisystem                 Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev                          16G       0   16G    0% /dev
tmpfs                        3,2G    218M  3,0G    7% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   85G     16G   66G   20% /
tmpfs                         16G    268K   16G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         16G       0   16G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    473M    219M  231M   49% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M    3,4M  508M    1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        4,8G       0  4,8G    0% /var/cache/unifi-video
tmpfs                        3,2G     60K  3,2G    1% /run/user/1000
/home/dirk/.Private           85G     16G   66G   20% /home/dirk
/dev/md0                     917G    359G  512G   42% /media/dirk/59b80d1c-3259-4cf7-b56e-0b24d55f1111
/dev/sdd1                     55G    2,0G   51G    4% /media/dirk/aa14e361-6aff-4d42-8a7b-78c8fba2c759
```

I am wondering if LVM has quit his service to fit the vm dynamic to the physical drive? How further to investigate this isse I (my server) ran in?

Comment: maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system#32505 will help you

Comment: I like to understand it. The link seems to show how to convert a physical into virtual.

Comment: Or other way around the link shows how to convert virtual to physical. I prefere to use my virtual further and to fix the guest or host that the pysical free disk space is used by the vm.

Comment: So you want to grow your vm? I am not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Maybe try this, https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system , and go to the first answer. That one is confirmed by the asker

Comment: Meanwhile I have resized the vdi and resized LVM with GParted, but apt-get upgrade shows me still not enough free space. I have to make a research how to be able to fix it (webserver Apache just shows "error" at the Homepage, Maybe because of inssuficient diskspace). If you might help please tell me with which commands (how-to) see this space for the server.

Comment: try lsblk (LiSt BLocK), it shows size for disks and partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete all snapshots of the vm running out of diskspace that you just have on current state and one vdi file
2. Resize the vdi from initial size to a size you like and can with

VBoxManage modifymedium /home/user/vm/server.vdi --resize x (where x is the desired new total space in megabytes)

3. Boot VM with GParted ISO-Image and fit logical volumen of the vm to the new size.
4. Boot VM Ubuntu OS and do

sudo lvresize -L xx.xxG /dev/ubuntu-tt-vg/root

and

sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-tt-vg/root xxxxxxx (where x are the number of blocks)

(might be that the path looks other than /dev/ubuntu-tt-vg/root for example /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root, figure that therefor out with fdisk -l)