# How to create an Ubuntu distro from VirtualBox Ubuntu Image?

Tags: virtualbox, packaging, disk-image, distro-recommendation

I have an UbuntuServer installed and filled with packages that I need, and it's ready for work.

Can I make a distro from VirtualBox image of UbuntuServer in to `.iso` installable file with all the packages that I have setted up?

EDITED:
I am sking how to create a distro from Virtual Machine and not how to convert Physical Machine in to Virtual machine.

Comment: @Rinzwind I am asking how to create a distro from Virtual Machine, and not how to convert Physical Machine in to Virtual machine.

Comment: Ah. Sorry I misread then. As an apology see https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vm-iso

Comment: Not an .iso but very good answer [https://askubuntu.com/a/32506/747387](https://askubuntu.com/a/32506/747387)

Comment: @Melebius Thank you your answer helped in some sort.