# Copy Ubuntu Server 18.04 to other Ubuntu Machine

Tags: server, vmware, ubuntu-core, clone

Am having Ubuntu Server 18.04 core with LAMP and other supporting packages installed. I want to migrate all of its content files and installed packages to a other machine with the same Ubuntu Server 18.04 core. I want this new machine to perform exactly as the older machine.

Please note: I don't know what other packages are installed in it, how can i perform this?

Answer (score 1):

You could clone the disk and insert it into the other machine.

Comment: The running system is physical while the new one is virtual. How can I clone this?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system