# How to clone a virtual machine (.vdi) to a physical system?

Tags: boot, partitioning, virtualbox, lubuntu, clone

I've spent 3 weeks trying to solve this, but to no avail. I'm aware of the many posts on this topics.

I've already read and tried at least:

[Migrate from a virtual machine (VM) to a physical system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system)
[Convert VirtualBox (VM) Machine TO Physical Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZUXtXU4YHQ)
[DD tutorial - how to clone, backup and restore disks and partitions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcF4JoFqd9E)
[restore using dd will not boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81708/restore-using-dd-will-not-boot)

I've created a lubuntu 20.04 with certain packages and files in a VM.
But I can't install it into a physical laptop (need to make many identical laptops with same configs). I can wipe all drives so I don't need to worry about dual boot.

Steps I've taken:
VM system: virtual box 7.0 (created a lubuntu 20.04), 10Gb
Laptop system: 125Gb (want to install lubuntu 20.04 with files/packages)

1. Created a lubuntu VM with fixed partition (not dynamic allocation)
2. I've created an .img and tried both with `VBoxManage...` and `dd` within the VM.
3. Booted into a Live usb installed lubuntu on the laptop disk then `dd` the img file into `sda` (the disk not sda1)

When I run `lsblk` the boot partition is missing unlike the results of [Convert VirtualBox (VM) Machine TO Physical Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZUXtXU4YHQ).

4. I've tried to offset and install the MBR but the VM does not have a boot partition only sda1
5. I've tried `install-mbr` (but not in depth)

At this point and age I feel that this is important enough that there's a tool. It looks like that this question has been asked for over a decade.

Thanks : )

Comment: This plan seems suboptimal for a number of reasons. A tool like [FAI](https://fai-project.org/) will make rapid deployments (and device reassignments) child’s play while also taking into account device-specific drivers that need to be installed on different models of hardware. Cloning a VBox image will just lead to excessive post-image work to clean up the remnants of the VM intermediary layer 

Comment: As I recall, you need to start VBox before using the `VBoxManage clonemedium` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it successfully on a non-UEFI machine (not claiming that it won't work on a UEFI machine, I just haven't tried it).

I used my go-to tool for such things, Clonezilla. I booted the VM using a Clonezilla .iso and cloned the disk to a shared drive on my server.

I then booted the physical machine using a Clonezilla thumbdrive and restored the clone off the server.

It worked fine. I did go in and remove the Guest Additions from the physical machine by going to `/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-(version)` and running the  `uninstall.sh` with sudo. (Guest Additions were causing a message to appear somewhere - I forget the details) I probably could have done that before cloning had I thought of it.