# Transfer virtual machine setup to laptop

Tags: system-installation, virtualization, vmware, disk-image

I spend four days creating a desktop environment as I need on VMware VM.
All is working great, and now I would like to install/copy/transfer this beautiful configuration to my new laptop. I don't want to spend another 3-5 days with configurations.

I tried to create a bootable image, but this was mistake because I created image with `*.vmdk` files and I need installation files/folder.

How I can transfer or create an installation image from my current VM?

Comment: You can clone the virtual system using Clonezilla and then install it on hardware. Posting as comment because I've done it on virtualbox but not on VMware. See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1462259/243321

Comment: This will only work if your laptop does not have any parts that require proprietary drivers, such as graphics and WiFi cards. There may be other differences between the virtual hardware of the VM and the physical laptop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a virtual machine (.vdi) to a physical system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462248/how-to-clone-a-virtual-machine-vdi-to-a-physical-system)